# Facebook Login implementation failing for React Native App

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I've been trying to implement Facebook Login functionality for react native app. Sad how a language developed by Facebook is not properly supporting its own functionalities. Here is the process I've followed:

1. I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next package as `npm i react-native-fbsdk-next` which installed `"^4.0.0"` of this.
2. I did `pod install` and it shows a success message as shown in the image below:
   [image]
3. Then I opened the iOS project in XCode and added this in my `info.plist` file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
          <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
          <array>
              <string>fbMY_APP_ID</string>
          </array>
      </dict>
  </array>
  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>MY_APP_ID</string>
  <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
  <string>MY_APP_NAME</string>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
  </array>
```

4. After that I opened `AppDelegate.m` and did the following:

```
...
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
  
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  return NO;
}

...
```

Then when I run the app `react-native run-ios` there is this really long error that appears and I cannot even copy the full one but here are the last few lines of that error:

Full Log of this error is posted https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/11

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> Ld /Users/chaudhrytalha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fbexampleapp-cbjnhmdbrulusmcwnknqvzbhuegw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fbexampleapp.app/fbexampleapp
> normal

The failer message is ever larger than that.

So far what I've tried is I've started a new project from scratch made sure it's running and the moment I install `react-native-fbsdk-next` and then update `pod` and run the app again it starts to show this long error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your project in xcode and create an empty .swift file in your project [image]

click next and your project will build

Comment: Is it just me or this is not really in the documentation? This swift file fixes it!

Comment: it isn't in the documentation I found this fix in a GitHub issue, but it fixes this